# SIMPLE SQLite query on intranet will not pull data from spiceworks

Tags: php, html, sqlite

I have been tasked with making a company intranet page. My boss wants a little section that displays "open tickets" from spiceworks on the index of the website. Below is the code i am using, it connects fine but i dont get anyresults, only a blank page, PLEASE HELP..  Its a windows 2003 server running IIS PHP5 SQLite.   I am not a programmer so please explain in english.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
try
{$db = new PDO('sqlite:C:\Program Files\Spiceworks\db\spiceworks_prod.db ');}
catch( PDOException $e )
{die( $e->getMessage() );}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tickets';
$out=$db->query($sql);
echo $out
```

Comment: Just as a test, do you get anything printed out if you replace that last echo with var_dump($out); ?

Comment: Yes i do, i get" bool(false) "   Just a quick note too, i know the database has data in it because i can browse it.

Comment: Do the file permissions allow the IIS user to access it?

Comment: @CL - Yes, i added "everyone" with read/write permissions with the same result. Does the code itself look right?  If the code is right atleast ill know where to start.

Comment: The code seems correct and the bool/false thing suggests you get nothing as a result of the query. What does var_dump($db) say?

Comment: Can you please check the php error log file to see if there's an entry reflecting an error?